# Как запустить Selenium server (RC) через Jenkins на виртуальной машине?

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, pytest

Я пытаюсь автоматизировать тесты с помощью Дженкинса. Принцип работы заключается в следующем: есть основная машина (ubuntu 22), на которой хранятся тесты (pyTest) и создаются виртуальные машины (Ubuntu 18 и 20), и дженкинс подключен к основной машине.

Проблема заключается в следующем: я пытаюсь запустить Selenium Server из Jenkins на виртуальной машине, выполнив команду:

```
sh '''ssh user@ip java -jar ~/selenium_driver/selenium-server-4.3.0.jar standalone -p 1234 > logs.log 2>&1'''
```

Хотя я избавился от вывода данных на консоль, но шаг в дженкинсе по-прежнему "зависает" в ожидании завершения команды и не переходит к следующему шагу.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Чтобы выполнить следующий шаг, после выполнения команды запуска selenium server. Возможно, вы сможете перейти к следующему шагу, не дожидаясь завершения предыдущего. Я использую конвейер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
stage('NameStage') {
    timeout(time: 20, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        sh """
            ssh user@ip 'java -jar ~/selenium_driver/selenium-server-4.3.0.jar standalone -p 1234 > ~/logs.log 2>&1'
        """
    }
}
```

Спустя 20 сек шаг завершается, селениум при этом остается работать в фоне